# What is the best way to set onClickListener inside getView() method?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

After watching this Google I/O video [The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) I understand that `getView()` is called multiple times. I want to set a `OnClickLister` inside `getView()` like this way.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //code goes here
    }
});
```

I want to know if there is a better way to do it than setting the `OnClickLister` in `getView()`?

Comment: what does *getView() calling is undefined* mean?

Comment: that means getView() is called multiple times.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are asking. If you have a `Button` in your list that performs some action than of course you need to set a click listener on it. But if the whole list item itself is clickable than you should use `listView.setOnItemClickListener(...);`.

Comment: Its not the whole listitem just only a button inside getView().

Comment: Yeah well as I said that set a click listener on it? What else are you going to do? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am going to insert data in the database each time when user click on only this button not the whole listitem.

Comment: So? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: onClickListener is called multiple times so the data is inserted multiple times.

Comment: Yes the getView called multiple times, is there anyway to avoid repeated call on click listener ?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...
    private OnClickListener mButtonClickListener;

    static class ViewHolder {
        ...
        public Button buttonHolder;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        holder.buttonHolder.setOnClickListener(this.mButtonClickListener);
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setButtonClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.mButtonClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

}
```

Then, you set it like this in your Activity/Fragment:

```
adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(...);
adapter.setButtonClickListener(mButtonListener);

private OnClickListener mButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    }

};
```